# How can I re-encrypt my laptop? After windows 11 dualboot with ubuntu 23.10

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, windows, encryption

How can I re-encrypt my laptop?

When I turned it on I had windows 11, and I wanted to dual boot it with ubuntu 23.10.

I had to disable the windows 11 bitlocker to install it.

After installation I can't find bitlocker in windows 11 to re-enable it,

What do you recommend or how can I re-encrypt windows 11 or both systems?

Comment: I have installed ubuntu 23.10

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1590327/1240908

Answer (score -1):

Windows settings/ Privacy and Security/Windows Security/Device security/manage Bitlocker drive encryption.
Pretty well buried.

Comment: it does not appear in any location in windows